# Substituting values in place of variables in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe as follows:

```
    df:
    Name    Age Type        Result
    Ra      35  adult       $name is an $type of $age years
    Ro      12  child       $name behaves like $type as he is $age years old 
    <+100 rows>
```

Each statement in Result column is different. All I need to do it populate the variable with proper values.

I am aware of multiple options like formatted strings and string format method but not able to understand how to implement it in a dataframe scenario as mentioned above:

```
Option 1:   f"Shepherd {name} is {age} years old."
Option 2:   "Shepherd {} is {} years old.".format(name, age)
```

Can anyone help with the usage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[format_map](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=format_map#str.format_map) takes a dictionary to replace the placeholders with the actual value.

The placeholders to use in our case is the column names.

[DataFrame.apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html?highlight=dataframe%20apply#pandas.DataFrame.apply) along `axis=1` uses  the `format_map` functionality for every row of the dataframe.

Make your csv like this:

```
Name    Age Type    Result
Ra  35  adult   {Name} is an {Type} of {Age} years
Ro  12  child   {Name} behaves like {Type} as he is {Age} years old
```

Code:

```py
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', sep='\t')
df['Result'] = df.apply(lambda row: row['Result'].format_map(row), axis=1)
print(df)
```

Output

```
  Name  Age   Type                                       Result
0   Ra   35  adult                   Ra is an adult of 35 years
1   Ro   12  child  Ro behaves like child as he is 12 years old
```

If you're not in a position to change the data, the code below will produce the same result as well.

```py
def str_substitute(row):
    return row['Result']\
        .replace('$name', row['Name'])\
        .replace('$type', row['Type'])\
        .replace('$age', str(row['Age']))
df['Result'] = df.apply(str_substitute, axis=1)
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Could you please include the logic for the lambda function in your answer so that it will be easier to understand? I am not able to change the data at the input level so I used the other solution.